# form :remote => true, submitted twice in IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer

I have a form tag with like following:

```
      <%= form_tag(new_invitations_invitations_path, :remote => true) do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:provider, "yahoo") %>
        <dl>
          <dt><strong>Your email:</strong></dt>
          <dd><%= text_field_tag('email') %></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
          <dt><strong>Password:</strong></dt>
          <dd><%= password_field_tag('pass') %></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
          <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
          <dd><%= submit_tag "Import your address book", :disable_with => "Please wait..." %></dd>
        </dl>
      <% end %>
```

Above gives output HTML as following:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/invitations/new_invitations" data-remote="true" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="EC+HcCqnxadujZg8CMWHGT1blQ3KoIddlnR8teWaowQ=" /></div>
  <input id="provider" name="provider" type="hidden" value="yahoo" />
  <dl>
    <dt><strong>Your email:</strong></dt>
    <dd><input id="email" name="email" type="text" /></dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt><strong>Password:</strong></dt>
    <dd><input id="pass" name="pass" type="password" /></dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
    <dd><input data-disable-with="Please wait..." name="commit" type="submit" value="Import your address book" /></dd>
  </dl>
```

When I try to submit above form in IE by pressing the submit button, the form is submitted twice. The problem is that once it is submitted with format as JS which is correct. And once it is submitted as HTML which is wrong. Because of second submission, I get a 406 not acceptable error.

Any clues?

Comment: do you have any javascript binding to this form's submit event?

Comment: No. I do not have any bindings. It turns out that I had older versions of rails.js in my application. Upgrading solved above problem.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below so people know this question is closed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be that I had older versions on Prototype and rails.js in my application. Upgrading solved the problem.