# Facebox seems to be sending HTML instead of JS with IE7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-7, facebox

I'm using Facebox to edit a record with my Ruby on Rails App. The Facebox pops up with edit form that I then submit to update the record with AJAX.

It works fine with Chrome, FireFox, Safari and IE8

with IE7 the link actually renders new page so it doesn't actually call AJAX and looking at server logs I see:

> Processing by Admin::Products::LicenseAssignmentsController#edit as
>   HTML (IE 7)

instead of

> Processing by Admin::Products::LicenseAssignmentsController#edit as JS
>   (other browsers)

Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: If I remember right IE messes with the headers in some way, do you have the JavaScript? That might jog my memory...

Comment: @Devin It's unobstrusive JavaScript with Rails.

Comment: What does your link look like in the view and HTML? What version of UJS and is it the new jQuery UJS or old Prototype UJS?

Comment: Can you post the content of your Admin::Products::LicenseAssignmentsController#edit method? Specifically, are you using respond_to?

Comment: I was also having same issues a few days ago. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925415/form-remote-true-submitted-twice-in-ie Try updating your `rails.js`. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that AJAX is called the order of components is required.
Check the order of the javascript libraries, and look at the log (console) browser.

P. S. This error only occurs in IE7?